# Why ClassNotFound Exception is given eventhoug we provide pre-defined classes?

Tags: java, class, exception

Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.Object"); why it's giving a ClassNotFound Exception even though i am providing a pre defined class?

Comment: Interesting, what environment are you compiling and running your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this. My best guess is that your classpath when you run Java is somehow defective and doesn't include the JRE.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin this my at environment variables